# Validate password and username in android by using httppost

Tags: java, android

Here are the javascript code that I validate the username and password. Can I do the HttpRequest in android to validate the username and password in the same manner? any example would be very appreciate.

The URL contains the username and password.

```
https://url.com/getdata?username=abcd123&password=123456

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", url, true);

req.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (req.readyState != 4) return;
    if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304)
    {
        return;
    }
    console.log(req.responseText);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). It's dead easy to use and it doesn't make you bother with some of the stuff you need to do with [DefaulHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) and the like. Here's how you do a POST:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("username", "abcd123");
params.put("password", "123456");

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post("https://url.com/getdata", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        // success
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable error, String content) {
        // something went wrong
    }
});
```

And a GET is as easy as:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post("https://url.com/getdata?username=abcd123&password=123456", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        // success
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable error, String content) {
        // something went wrong
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    private static String httpClient(String url) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        return sb.toString();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the url contains username and password or only the log in url?

Comment: the url should contain the username and password